# Cycles renders only part of the model

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was making a minecraft rig Timys rig v7 and when I went to render it only this rendered. it renders in blender mode to. but the sword and lighting is ugly as heck [image]

Comment: *"lighting is ugly as heck "* other than specifing what is wrong exactly, note that lighting has to be redone (if you don't like it) prior to rendering. Specify what specs of your computer are, what render did you start (animation or usual)

Comment: This is just another [square sample](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/64003/2217) problem. Cycles will render all of it, it will just take approximately another 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Cycles renders using tiles. The image shows only 4 of the 40 tiles it has to render. You have to wait...

[image]

You are likely rendering using CPU on a machine that has 4 cores. Blender will render 4 tiles simultaneously, then move to render 4 more until the whole picture is done.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Wait for the image to be done rendering....

Comment: I've waited like 10 hours before and it just never finishes

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96720/how-can-i-render-the-way-the-render-preview-renders/96723#96723

Comment: *"10 hours before and it just never finishes"* from the data on your screenshot last render was done in 30 seconds and this one was being done for 4 seconds

Comment: the 30 second one never finished i quit it ask questions before you think you know the answer

Comment: You do not explain everything about your problem and expect others to understand what is going on on your computer. *"the 30 second one never finished"* this can not happen just in that way. If render starts and shows tiles it will be finished. There's somehting else not mentioned. I don't think I know answer. I try to get more details to diagnose the problem. If you don't want to give them it's absolutely your choice, don't expect question will be answered though